# Material-UI: How to declare a type for React.ComponentType<P> with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I am using Typescript and [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) I want to declare the component type for a variable like this

```
import MoreVert from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert'
import { SvgIconProps } from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';

let myIcon: SvgIconProps = <MoreVert />; // does not work
```

But I am getting the error:

```
[ts]
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'SvgIconProps'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[This is how the SvgIcon.ts](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.d.ts) looks like. What am I doing wrong?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StandardProps, PropTypes } from '..';

export interface SvgIconProps
  extends StandardProps<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, SvgIconClassKey> {
  color?: PropTypes.Color | 'action' | 'disabled' | 'error';
  component?: React.ReactType<SvgIconProps>;
  fontSize?: 'inherit' | 'default' | 'small' | 'large';
  nativeColor?: string;
  titleAccess?: string;
  viewBox?: string;
}

export type SvgIconClassKey =
  | 'root'
  | 'colorSecondary'
  | 'colorAction'
  | 'colorDisabled'
  | 'colorError'
  | 'colorPrimary'
  | 'fontSizeInherit'
  | 'fontSizeSmall'
  | 'fontSizeLarge';

declare const SvgIcon: React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps>;

export default SvgIcon;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
`<MoreVert />` is a ReactNode type, has nothing to do with props, it's already applied. You might wanted something like `myIcon = MoreVert` without application

Comment: @Ebuall I am using typescript so I want to declare the type of it.

Comment: But you want to declare completely unrelated type.

Comment: @Ebuall That's why the question is here.

Comment: It just makes no sense.  
`MoreVert` already has type `React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps>`, 
`<MoreVert />` has type Element, and has nothing in common with props, you already applied props at this point.

Comment: How are you using `myIcon`?  That would help us figure out the type you are looking for.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen As a `SvgIcon`. Look at the variable declaration above. The type is incorrect as of now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

> By default the result of a JSX expression is typed as any. You can
>   customize the type by specifying the JSX.Element interface. However,
>   it is not possible to retrieve type information about the element,
>   attributes or children of the JSX from this interface. It is a black
>   box.

The reason why I lose all type information with `JSX.Element` is because it extends `React.ReactElement<any>` which has the type of `any`. To fix this I used it like this

```
 let myIcon: React.ReactElement<SvgIconProps> = <MoreVert />;
```

Now I have the element with all the type information.

Comment: The `SvgIconProps` interface can be imported via: `import { SvgIconProps } from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";`

Answer (score 4):

If anyone does not work by the way answered question of *@Murat Karagöz* you may try this when initializing an interface or a variable of an **Icons** from **Material UI** using **TypeScript**.

> I got this working by declaring like this:
>
> ```
> import ShowChartIconOutlined from '@material-ui/icons/ShowChartOutlined';
> import { SvgIconProps } from '@material-ui/core';
>
> type Menu = {
>   id: number;
>   icon: (props: SvgIconProps) => JSX.Element;
>   label: string;
> }[];
>
> const NavBarMenus: Menu = [
>   {
>     id: 1,
>     icon: ShowChartIconOutlined,
>     label: 'Dashboard',
>   },
> ...
> ];
> ```

*Reference*: [*[Docs & Types] Importing icons from @material-ui/icons in TypeScript #647*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537285/material-ui-how-to-declare-a-type-for-react-componenttypep-with-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

As already briefly described by Ebuall in a comment, here's how you would declare the variable depending on whether you want the JSX element or the component type:

```
let myIconElement: JSX.Element = <MoreVert />;
let MyIconComponent: React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps> = MoreVert;

// Example component that uses the icon
function myComponent(props: {}) {
    return <>
        {myIconElement}
        {<MyIconComponent />}
    </>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<MoreVert />` is a component.

`SvgIconProps` just define the list of props passed to this component.

You should try:

```
let myIcon: SvgIcon = <MoreVert />;
```

Comment: I tried that but the ts compiler complains that he can not find `SvgIcon` even with the import `import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon/SvgIcon';`

Comment: Wierd, because it's exported. So maybe `React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps>` ?

Comment: I also tried that it will lead to `Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: SvgIconProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.`